# Null object in Func

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a filter as below:

```
filter = project => project.Plan.ProgressStatus == progressStatus;
```

I am creating a filter based on `progressStatus` that is passed into method.

Then I pass this filter to a `where` operator.

```
var projects = _projectService.Where(filter);
```

I get back `NRE` since `Plan` is null.

How can I safely query objects whose Plan.ProgressStatus is equal to what i pass in as parameter?

Comment: If `Plan` is null, then *it doesn't have a `ProgressStatus`*. You basically have to ignore all projects that doesn't have a plan.

Comment: I am aware of that, how can i do this safely though?

Comment: Check for null. Why wouldn't that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your filter check if it is `null`:

```
filter = project => project.Plan != null && project.Plan.ProgressStatus == progressStatus;
```

If `_projectService` possibly contains `null` then add that check as well:

```
filter = project => project != null
                 && project.Plan != null 
                 && project.Plan.ProgressStatus == progressStatus;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a null check to the `project` and/or `project.Plan` objects in your func.

```
filter = project => 
{
    if(project == null || project.Plan == null)
        return false;
    return project.Plan.ProgressStatus == progressStatus;
};
```